# Trying to assign static IP address, subnet, gateway and vlan id for esxi host through racadm

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, dell

I am trying to prepare a script to assign Static IPv4 address for host. Usually I will take iDRAC console and I will update IP, subnet, GW and VLAN ID. But I have around 2500+ servers going forward to do. I tried using racadm setniccfg command but it updates the idrac IP.

[image]

In idrac console i will select Configure Management network --> then Vlan --> and on down I will give IPv4 Values. Attached is the picyure of iDRAC console page.

Comment: [scripted ESXI installation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.esxi.install.doc/GUID-00224A32-C5C5-4713-969A-C50FF4DED8F8.html) is pretty good documented. Did you try it?

Comment: Gerald, ESXi is pre-installed. I just have to assign static IP for it, then have to downgrade HBA driver FW.

Comment: Well, if you can't reach it via network the only way is a scripted reinstall. Use DHCP for the IP settings and you have to do next to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The DRAC - and subsequently *racadm* - doesn't configure the server network. It can be used to configure the RAC interface only.

The host can either be dynamically configured using DHCP or you can script the ESXi via SSH and `esxcli`:

```
~ # esxcli network ip interface add -?
Usage: esxcli network ip interface add [cmd options]

Description:
  add                   Add a new VMkernel network interface.

Cmd options:
  -P|--dvport-id=<str>  DVPort ID of the connection point. This requires --dvs-name to be given in the same command
  -s|--dvs-name=<str>   DVSwitch name of the connection point. This requires --dvport-id to be given in the same command
  -i|--interface-name=<str>
                        The name of the VMkernel network interface to create. This name must be in the form vmkX, where X is
                        a number 0-255
  -M|--mac-address=<str>
                        Set the MAC address for the newly created VMkernel network interface.
  -m|--mtu=<long>       Set the MTU setting for a given VMkernel network interface on creation
  -p|--portgroup-name=<str>
                        The name of the vswitch port group to add this VMkernel network interface to.
```

Comment: Okay. Is there any way that I can SSH the esxi without IP set on it. I tried with its name but it failed with error "Host does not exist".

Comment: The host should run DHCP and you can reserve an IP address on the DHCP server for its MAC address. DNS only works when set up properly.